# How we should pronounce /ɔː/ phonetician in American English?

Tags: phonetics

I have no problem with its pronunciation in British English, but in American English, yes. Do it have a sound like /əʊ/ as in 'go' or /ɒ/ as in 'got'?
And I know that /ɔː/ and /əʊ/ aren't pronounced exactly like each other, and /ɔː/ and /ɒ/, but I can't write the sounds and my mean is their likeness.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between /ɑ/ and /ɔ/ in American English?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6143/what-are-the-differences-between-%c9%91-and-%c9%94-in-american-english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit puzzled about your question, did you try [first google results](https://www.google.de/search?q=%C9%94%CB%90&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=5pdxVcegB6L6ygOF6YCgCg#q=%C9%94%CB%90%20english)?

[This](http://pronuncian.com/Lessons/Default.aspx?Lesson=32) lesson on pronuncian.com display a scheme, explain how to place your tongue and examples to listen.

[image]

> The entire tongue is pushed back and kept low during the pronunciation of the aw sound. [...]

---

There is also two articles, one on [teflpedia](http://teflpedia.com/IPA_phoneme_/%C9%94%CB%90/) and one on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_back_rounded_vowel) which look complete.

---

I may not have answered you question, can you be more specific about why are not you able to pronounce it?

Comment: Actually, there are differences between British and American pronunciations of the "aw" sound. The symbol /ɔ/ is convenient for representing this sound across dialects, and is approximately in the right place phonetically, but it only indicates the sound and manner of pronunciation in a rough way. British /ɔ/ tends to be realized higher in the mouth, more like [oː], while American /ɔ/, where not merged with /ɑ/, may be realized with a quality more like [ɒ]. Phonemic notation is often simplified and can't be trusted to describe actual speech sounds in detail!

Comment: @sumelic You can have examples of prononciation on wordreference.com, here for [law](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/law). It may help.